# Event handler deleted automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I create some event handler in Designer `InitializeComponents()`. The problem is, most of Event Handler that I create manually always disarpear (deleted) after I move another forms. For example, I create some Dragform in PictureBox like this:

```
    this.picLogo.MouseDown += picLogo_MouseDown;
    this.picLogo.MouseMove += picLogo_MouseMove;
    this.picLogo.MouseDown += picLogo_MouseDown;
```

After I move the PictureBox (picLogo), that code is gone. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Is this a Visual Studio problem, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding events manually to the designer, if something changes in the form visual studio will overwrite your changes.  There's a comment telling you this -

```
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
```

Try adding your events in the code behind (e.g. just after the call to InitializeComponent, or on the form load), or select the control in design mode, view properties, ciick the events button (at the top of properties, it looks like a lightening bolt) and you can add events there too.

Comment: OMG, I move it into form_load() ... I just know event handler can moved outside Designer. Thank you very much...

Comment: There's nothing magical about the code that executes in the .designer.cs file, except possibly that it executes inbetween BeginInit and EndInit for `ISupportInitialize` controls, but other than that you can do everything you can in that file in the .cs file.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : I see, thank you very much. I just moved to C# today. This simple problem cost me 2 hours after searching in google and this forum.

Answer (score 1):

`InitializeComponents` method has nice comment:

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   // ...
}

#endregion
```

This comment clearly says that you should not modify contents of this method with the code editor. Why? Because as region name states, this method is generated by form designer. Each time it will be re-generated all your manual changes will be gone. This method is re-generated when you change form in designer (e.g. move some control, like PictureBox).